# How to change the frequency of Google Play update checks?

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, updates

Every day I get a notification on my Inc2 that there are app updates available in the market.  Is there a way to change the frequency of these update checks?  I see no reason to be prompted to update my apps on a daily basis and this is a little annoying.  I would like to be able to only have it check for updates weekly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off automatic update checking by pressing menu and than settings in the play store. You can then manually go to my apps to update them. This will not greatly increase the work you have to do, because even if there is a notification once a week it would still require you to confirm the updates. There is no option however to change the frequency of the automatic updates.

Answer (score 2):

If you go into Settings and check "Auto-update apps" it will download and install the updates without prompting you. If you're worried about data usage, also check "Update over Wi-FI only". I've had my phone set this way for a while now, as I too got tired of constantly having updates to accept.

As Dylan Yaga pointed out, if an apps update changes its permissions, you will still be prompted to update it manually, although this doesn't occur very often.

Comment: Side Note: Apps that change permissions must still be manually reviewed before updating using this method.

Comment: I like being in control of when my apps update.  Daily is far to often to review a list of updates.  I assume that if I auto-update I will still be notified of all of the updates that have occurred.  I have also found that quite a few of my apps update permissions frequently.

Comment: I finally gave in and went this route.  I still don't like apps autoupdating without telling me, but at least my monthly update all doesn't freeze up the device for an hour anymore.